# OP edits question to a completely new question instead of providing MCVE

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, specific-question

So the OP posted a XSLT [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714200/system-line-seperator-when-creating-an-html-document-with-jaxb) that wasn't really a bad question but did not have enough information to actually answer it.

Because of this, I posted a comment asking for some example input and output data along with the XSLT they were attempting.  I got back a response that the input data is a 20k line file and can't possibly be posted.  I posted another comment telling them to provide some data (not all) needed to see exactly what they were attempting and what was going wrong, linking to the [mcve article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The OP responding by saying that it was too difficult to explain (I don't think it was - it was just a little unclear and an example would clarify it completely) and not important.  They then edited the question to be a completely different question.

I'm not saying that they changed it a little.  The question they edited to is only related to the original in the sense that it covers the same language.  It is not remotely the same question.

What is the expected etiquette on this?  Should the question be flagged in any way for this?

I would expect that with a different question a new question should be opened.  It shouldn't be edited over the original.  If the OP wanted to abandon the question, they should delete it.

Comment: If nobody's answered it, there's not much real harm in the edit.

Comment: Looks like it is deleted now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expected etiquette is that you don't do this; once someone has started responding to a question, whether via comments or answers, it's important that the question remain more or less the same. Changing it to a completely different question is dishonest and not allowed, since users no longer "own" their content once it's posted.

You are within your rights to rollback such a massive and complete edit, but please also leave a comment explaining why, so that the OP does not do it again or feel tempted to enter a rollback war. If such a war does start, just flag the question for moderator attention and they will either lock the post or disassociate the OP from it.

Comment: I asked this once in chat some time back. The response I got was that comments are ephemeral and as long as there were no answers to invalidate, a complete rewrite (re-purpose) was a non-issue. So is this answer still valid? It is valid for closed/deleted post?

Comment: @Scratte Comments are ephemeral, but more accurately comments are *second-class citizens*. They *can* stick around for a long time, if they are valuable. It's just that it's also easy for them to disappear forever without a trace, so we prefer valuable info be put in an answer. As for not replacing your question with a new one after comments, it's less of an issue than if there are answers already, but it's still rude to waste the time of those who have helped or put in effort trying to understand your solution. So for answers, think: "do not"; for comments, think: "should not", if that helps.

Comment: It does, sort of :) I am mostly interested in closed/deleted Questions, where there are only comments and there's noway to bring a Question back on track with it's current content or topic. I'm aware that the comments show effort into the original Question, but once it's closed or deleted, wouldn't the comments have already been wasted? I'm not referring to duplicate closures, as they have their own value.

Comment: @Scratte You can usually undelete a question, so ultimately the effort isn't wasted unless of course the question was *so* off-topic that no amount of editing will make it on-topic. If you can edit *those* questions to be on-topic, you're almost surely just *asking a completely different question*... so you should post that different question via the 'ask a question' button rather than the 'edit' button.

Comment: Some Questions are just so bad that they have no value, no matter how they're rephrased. When users are Question banned, they are told to edit their Questions and get them back on track. That will not be possible for them unless they actually edit them. Even if they are not absolutely hopeless, they are not likely to bring those Questions back to being good with edits, because the premise of the initial Question just cannot become useful. Very good examples of those are Questions closed as typo's. There's just noway to edit them, and certainly not while still making existing comments relevant.

Comment: @Scratte There are other ways to provide 'positive contributions' that the system considers for question bans. On top of that, you can always ask a new question once every (either 100 days or 6 months... I forget which). Other than that, if you get a question ban and strike out on ways to fix it, then we probably *really* don't want your contributions on the site.

Comment: Which other ways? Answering does not.